# Can I get a user ID that clicked "Like" on one of my pages? And can I put "Like" button for post on facebook to my site?

Tags: facebook, button, plugins, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Can I get a user ID that clicked "Like" on one of my pages? I tried to make it through the FQL but so far unsuccessful.

And can I put "Like" button for post on facebook to my site? For example I have some post on my facebook page and I want to let the user click "Like" for this post while he or she on my site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to prompt the user for user_likes extended permission for that FQL query to work.

To have them like a Facebook wall post, you would need to prompt for publish_stream extended permission and then do an HTTP POST to /postid/likes

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that I want all the users who clicked "like" and not only friends of user. Is it possible?

And if I call $fql->api('/postid/likes') it will return users who like this post isn't it?

Comment: Facebook wont give you all the users who like your page due to privacy reasons.